# Understanding Wcf Service Endpoint Logic

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I developed a wcf service that makes database operations for me. And works on an address like https://blahblah.com/myService.svc

When I wrote this url to browser, its ok, it works, no problem.

And I developed an asp.net project that uses this wcf service. In my asp.net web.config there is an endponint attribute like this:

```
<endpoint address="https://blahblah.com/myService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
```

In localhost(without https) it works with this endpoint address. But in server's IIS it doesn't work and throws error "There was no endpoint..."

When I change the address to this:

```
<endpoint address="https://blahblah.com/myService.svc/myService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
```

it's working with this config. I don't understand why it's working with this configuration in server's IIS. Can anyone explain the logic of this situation?

Comment: You need to provide your configuration file and how you posted it on iis.

Answer (score 0):

It might occur on the below condition :

1. Your service name and folder name is same in IIS (myService.svc) . i.e inside the folder named 'myService.svc' your service called 'myService.svc' may present

OR

2. You might have set the Alias name as 'myService.svc' in IIS. (To verify, click on your site --> Basic Setting --> Alias

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no folder "myService.svc". There is on folder "myService" and IIS web site explores this folder, and this folder contains "myService.svc"

I couldn't see "Alias" in Basic Settings. But my service hosted with domain and it's https.